# Increase the width of a Qualtrics slider value box

Tags: javascript, html, css, qualtrics

I've created a Qualtrics Survey slider and included the option to show value to the right side, but as my values are in millions the value is getting cut off. Is there a way to increase the width of the label text box?  Guessing the answer might be JavaScript.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  

    $('#QID92\\~\\2\\~\\ResultsTd').css('width',500);  

});
```

Comment: where is your tested code?

Comment: Sorry, just added it to the original post.

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to increase the size of the shown value, not the label. is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without JavaScript.

Add the following to  the html view of your question text.

```
<style>
    .Skin .horizontalbar table.sliderGrid tr td.value input{
        width: 9em;
    }
    .Skin .QuestionBody{
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

This will allow the Question to stretch to fit the container, and then increase the size of the input box.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: Not a problem! If this worked for you, it would be helpful if you marked it as correct.